# Dollar sign to Peso Sign

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This code:

```
string currentPrice = String.Format("{0:c}", ((TblProduct)e.ListItem).Price);
```

shows the price in dollars, ie `$320.00`. But I want to show a peso sign instead of a dollar sign. What system.string should I use? `{?:?}`

Comment: "Help" is not needed in your title. It is implicit that you need help.

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify an additional argument (a format provider) in order to acquire the appropriate currency symbol and formatting.  For example, to format for the Philippines:

```
var currentPrice = String.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-PH"),
                                 "{0:c}",
                                 ((TblProduct)e.ListItem).Price);
```

If a format provider is not specified, `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is used.

Comment: @mikez, fair point, but in that context $ is a peso sign, right? ;)

Comment: In fact, as far as I can tell, $ is the peso sign worldwide but for the Republic of the Philippines where it is ₱; I've edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one works for me.
im using a Unicode character escape sequence which is "\u" then followed by its hexidecimal unicode value.

[Unicode Character 'PESO SIGN' (U+20B1)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b1/index.htm)

`string currentPrice = String.Format("\u20B1{0}", ((TblProduct)e.ListItem).Price);`